# Как развернуть HTML Symbol Entities?

Tags: html, css

Знак ⇱ необходимо развернуть чтобы стрелка указывала в правую верхнюю сторону. Пробовал указывать transform: scale(-1, 1); вроде работало но элемент переносило в правую часть экрана, а хотелось бы чтобы он развернулся и стоял на том же самом месте(

Comment: к какому элементу ты применяешь transform?

Comment: вообще надо к ссылке типа a, но там совсем не работало, поэтому я пробовал к диву а в див ссылку, там работало но оно текст вправо экрана переносит( вот пример http://jsfiddle.net/wp6kscep/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так работает:

```
начало
Текст, который мы повернем
<a target="_blank" href="/rezume/detail/2017-4-r77">
<div class="rotatable">⇱</div></a>
конец

.rotatable {
  transform: scale(-1, 1);
  display: inline-block;
}
```

[Исправленный jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wp6kscep/2/)

Comment: ну символ то из общего текста перелетел в правую часть экрана( а этого не должно быть

Comment: Поправил. Не перелетает.

Comment: после исправления да) спс